# PHPUnit and Selenium exampe 17.1

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, selenium, phpunit

I'm trying to run the example from PHPUnit with selenium 17.1 ([Link](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/selenium.html#selenium.selenium2testcase.examples.WebTest.php))

I have done all installation but it keeps failing.

I just get:

```
 1) WebTest::testTitle
BadMethodCallException: The command http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/url is not recognized by the server.
```

I havent changed anything to the example. The Selenium server is running.

I can't figure out what is wrong. Help?

**ANSWER:**

**Please see @rutter's comment:**
*Do you know what version of PHPUnit_Selenium you're running? This is reported fixed as of 1.3.2 (changelog, pull request). – rutter*

In addition to that after 2 weeks this project startet working again. I think a simple reinstall is all that it needed. :)

Comment: Interesting. I just cloned the latest PHPUnit and downloaded Selenium 2.34.0, and had the same problem. Notice that the sessionId is missing from the URL in that error message? It should be `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/<sessionId>/url`. Well, I dug into the source, it appears that the sessionId is not being appended to the URL. Here's a hack: in `PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Response.php`, modify the `getURL` method to `return new PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_URL($this->info['url'].'/'.$this->jsonResponse['sessionId']);`. This got the tests to pass. Not ideal though.

Comment: Do you know what version of PHPUnit_Selenium you're running? This is reported fixed as of 1.3.2 ([changelog](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/ChangeLog.markdown), [pull request](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/pull/266)).

Comment: @rutter Thanks for asking. I actually think this has been fixed as they say because i gave it about 2 weeks and now it just startet working. Don't know how, but it works! :D

Comment: You should answer your own question here and check it as the right answer so others who find this know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

Please see @rutter's comment: *Do you know what version of PHPUnit_Selenium you're running? This is reported fixed as of 1.3.2 (changelog, pull request). – rutter*

In addition to that after 2 weeks this project startet working again. I think a simple reinstall is all that it needed. :)